# TS2339: Property not recognized on alternating type

Tags: typescript

```
type NotifyOptions = {
    className: string
    timeout?: null | number
} & ({ text: string } | { html: string })


export default function notify(options: NotifyOptions) {
  if(options.text) {
    console.log(options.text)
  }
}
```

> Property 'text' does not exist on type 'NotifyOptions'.
> Property 'text' does not exist on type '{ className: string; timeout?: number | null | undefined; } & { html: string; }'.(2339)

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAlgMxAeTEuA7AzlAXigG8AoKCqAYwBsBDXXGOgWwgC4pdgAnRbAOblKSNnACuwAPyds4mjSgAfKHJYAjCD1IBfKADIoACmJRgEAB7BO3PoKh6VpgBbAWNG734CHASlIBlmBwPMBQACYQyHTyYcji2FRY2KoIKCBGcJiIOLic8EioGMm4viTCKJnZuQB05lZlZJTUuXA0EDU0cAJVJXWWwP4UOrpAA)

Why is it saying `options.text` doesn't exist? It should be typed as `string|undefined` I think.

Answer (score 2):

[This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAlgMxAeTEuA7AzlAXigG8AoKKAYwBsBDXXGWgWwgC4pdgAnRbAcwDc5KElZwArsAD8HbBOrUoAHyjzmAIwjdhAXygAyKAAoyFANZ8AJhwBEAC2DNqt4RUfOOXXgL3KzUJbYNlC2wBAAHsCuIuFRXjx8QqS6AJTCpJFgcNzAUFYQyLQKecgS2JRY2GoIKCDGcJiIOLgc8EioGFW4qSQiKCaN3QB0QVaEBERhkdG9ARSULXDUEMPUcPwNTS3DccDpIroiENS40ChbI2MTUx4ucyILSytrG5fNeMN3BxRHR0A) shows a working example which does allow a 'discriminated union'. The way this works is it separates out a specific type, using the kind of check that Typescript can actually exploit (a literal equality). See [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions).

```
type NotifyOptions = {
  className: string;
  timeout?: null | number;
} & ({
  kind: "html";
  html: string;
}|{
  kind: "text";
  text: string;
});

export default function notify(options: NotifyOptions) {
  if (options.kind === "text") {
    console.log(options.text);
  }
  else if(options.kind === "html") {
    console.log(options.html);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the way typescript works, you can only reference properties which exist in all cases of the union. Hence the need to have a `kind` property. You can see when jcalz schooled me on this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495776/2257198

If your case can really afford not to take any notice of the type system (e.g. you are only interested in the presence of the property and being able to dereference it regardless of its type) then the smallest change to your original code is to use the `in` operator, which eliminates the compiler error like this.

```
export default function notify(options: NotifyOptions) {
  if("text" in options) {
    console.log(options.text)
  }
}
```

You could go even further down the javascript typing route, again if you don't care for Typescript types for your case...

```
export default function notify(options: NotifyOptions) {
  if("text" in options && typeof options.text === "string") {
    console.log(options.text)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript will only allow you to access properties common to each member of the union.

On the other hand, it will not allow you to access properties defined only in one member of the union.

The assumption that members existing on one member of the union do not exist in the other members may not be true in practice: thay may exist, and the type of the property may be different.
Thus assuming that `options.text` is string or undefined is deemed not safe.

Consider the following example:

```
const o = {
    className: 'c1',
    timeout: 3000,
    html: 'ht',
    text: 4
};
const opt: NotifyOptions = o;
```

I created a NotifyOptions where text is a number.

Typescript 3.2 introduced [Non-unit types as union discriminants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants)

> TypeScript 3.2 makes narrowing easier by relaxing rules for what it considers a discriminant property. Common properties of unions are now considered discriminants as long as they contain some singleton type (e.g. a string literal, null, or undefined), and they contain no generics.

You can write:

```
type NotifyOptions = {
    className: string
    timeout?: null | number
} & ({ text: string; html?: undefined; } 
   | { html: string; text?: undefined})
```

Typescript allows you to access the properies and treat them as the discriminants of the union.

On top of that, assignment of `o` constant to NotifyOptions is not allowed anymore.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAlgMxAeTEuA7AzlAXigG8AoKCqAYwBsBDXXGOgWwgC4pdgAnRbAOblKSNnACuwAPyds4mjSgAfKHJYAjCD1IBfKADIoAChJRgEAB7BO3PoIDcUABbAWNTuOwATCMn4QvRx1hSiViZ1d3Ll5%20AUdzKxkoTx8-bACdAEpSHMswOB5gKFS6eSLkTyosbFUEFBAjOExEHFxOeCRUDGrcTJJhFEbm1oA6BOA%20skpqVrgaCBGaOAEhnrHLCeFg4NIqVqK4Qn6KWgYmVg4oAHIqK4AaYVEICWsoAGYABi%20Hihc3Tiufxo92EAHpQWYNpwACy6HJ7PBFbB1LpgEDtFHoYZ4I5wexAA)